# How to access Kotlin companion object in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

I convert one of my Java class to Kotlin and the class as below.

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        operator fun get(context: Context): MainApplication {
            return context.applicationContext as MainApplication
        }
    }
}
```

It has a static function `get`.

I still have a Java function accessing it.

```
MainApplication application = MainApplication.get(mContext);
```

It was good when MainApplication is in Java. But not when MainApplication in Kotlin, the above code error

```
Error:(27, 54) error: cannot find symbol method get(Context)
```

How could I access `get` in my Java code above?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can add [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods) annotation to the method in companion object to make Kotlin generate a static method.

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun get(context: Context): MainApplication {
            return context.applicationContext as MainApplication
        }
    }
}
```

you can then access it from Java like before converting to Kotlin:

```
MainApplication application = MainApplication.get(mContext);
```

EDIT: I feel obliged to add something I learned recently: `@JvmStatic` doesn't actually **move** where the method gets generated. It **duplicates** it, by generating a static method for Java in addition to the method on the companion object. Personally I think this isn't great and it can have some implications depending on a use case, so something worth knowing.

Comment: Nice one. Looks like there are two ways. Depends on which side (kotlin or java) we could change.

Comment: Tick this as 'the' answer, given it's more likely one had to make the Kotlin compatible with Java than vice versa. (i.e. people likely to convert from Java to Kotlin, and work on the Kotlin code instead of Java code).

Comment: The other answer (mine) i.e. using `MainApplication.Companion.get(mContext);` is also a good answer :)

Comment: according to official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html you should use `@JvmField` in this scenario and NOT  `@JvmStatic`

Comment: @JvmField is for properties, not functions. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/

Answer (score 37):

Ops, I got it. Just use the below.

```
MainApplication application = MainApplication.Companion.get(mContext);
```

Comment: You can also name the companion object if you don't like the default `Companion` name.

Comment: Just not good when there is a major refactor and you have to change all these places. The JvmStatic option on the other hand will not need chnages in many places.

Answer (score 11):

By omitting the name of your companion object, the name `Companion` must be used to access the methods.

Example:

```
class MyClass1 {
    companion object Object1 {
        fun method1 {
        }
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
    companion object {
        fun method2 {
        }
    }
}
```

To invoke the first companion object method you would do the following:

```
MyClass1.method1()
```

To invoke the second:

```
MyClass2.Companion.method2()
```

See the Kotlin docs on [Companion Objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) for details.

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.1.50 you can call functions of the companion object by omitting the `companion` key word

Comment: not if you are calling the companion object from Java and it doesn't have a name.

Comment: I had to use `MyClass1.Object1.method1()`, but this worked best, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter a problem where you cannot access the Companion object's method in Java if the `new` keyword is used in the method call. The `new` keyword should be omitted. The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html) states:

> Companion objects and their members can only be accessed via the containing class name, not via instances of the containing class.

So if you have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        fun create() {}
    }
}
```

You can call the companion object's method like this:

`MyClass.create()`

But not like this:

`new MyClass.create`