# How to access Kotlin companion objects from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-companion

I have this Kotlin class:

```
class Storage {
    companion object {
        val COL_ID = "id"
    }
}
```

and I want to use the `COL_ID` in my Java code:

```
doSomething(Storage.COL_ID);
```

but, the compiler tells me that `COL_ID` is private. I have tried to add `public` to all the elements (class, object and val), but it has no effect.

How can I access these companion object constants?

**Update** I think my question is different from the given duplicate, because I want to create constants, instead of a static method.

Comment: You are missing `const` from your `const val COL_ID` (or `@JvmField`)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that simple ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Kotlin companion object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120494/how-to-access-kotlin-companion-object-in-java)

Comment: @Steve no, it finds it, it just was not accesible.

Comment: Hmmm...I wouldn't think that would work.  Ok, well, I don't understand it then.  So what was the solution you ultimately came up with?  You said you already tried making it 'public'

Comment: I'm new to Kotlin, so I'd really like to understand your soluton.  All I can make work in my own IDE is: **Storage.Companion.getCOL_ID()** unless I add the @JvmStatic annotation

Comment: @Steve see my updated question and answer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - cool.  I'm still at a loss for what's going on here, as I don't see why making this 'const' would change how it is referenced.  Do you have any insight into that? - +1'd your answer btw.

Comment: @Steve See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-does-kotlin-need-const-keyword/8446/3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added `const`, and everything was fine:

```
class Storage {
    companion object {
        const val COL_ID = "id"
    }
}
```