# How to pass companion object output in Kotlin as parameter in object creation in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin library to my java android project
Kotlin lib. have 2 classes

```
class MyClass1{
  constructor(param1 ,param2,param3){}
   public companion object {
     val S1= MyClass1(param1,param2,param3)
     val S2= MyClass1(param1,param2,param3)
   }
}


class MyClass2 {
 (private var loc: Location?, private var method: MyClass1?)
}
```

I need to pass S1 or S2 to constructor of MyClass2 in Java

`MyClass2 newClass= MyClass2(loc, MyClass1.S1);`

I found that I should use Companion before S1 , but I got error => Method call expected

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you post what is your desired output and go through the code again? Syntax for `MyClass2` also looks dubious

Comment: How to assign S1 to second param to newClass object from Java .                                  MyClass2 newClass= MyClass2(loc, MyClass1.S1);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Kotlin companion object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120494/how-to-access-kotlin-companion-object-in-java)

Comment: Also, read the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields)

Comment: I tried both but cannot access S1,I got  getS1() instead of S1                                                                                 ```MyClass2 newClass= MyClass2(loc, MyClass1.Companion.getS1());     ```

Comment: The code you posted in the comment should work